# PHP - read file to array, search array for partial match

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm reading a text file using:
`$array = file('testfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

This results in an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123746,1,801632,157459
    [2] => 123852,0,804353,123985
    [3] => 121520,1,824103,148532
    [4] => 123477,0,824973,175268
    ......
    [26075] => 167377,1,829803,170358
)
```

I'm trying search that array using the following:

```
if ( in_array( '824103', $array ) ) {
    echo "MATCH";
}
```

But I never get a match, How do I search for a partial match in the value ?

I want to search the array and return the matching row.

Thanks

Comment: you need a loop

Comment: You could use `array_filter()` with a custom function

Comment: Are you searching for a matching value (between commas) or just simple string match?  (ie if you search for '824103' do you want to match '123,9982410399,456' or not?)

Comment: @RobEyre I want to search for '824103' and return the matching line. Thanks

Comment: `$found = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return strpos($v, '824103') !== false;}); if (!empty($found)) { ...` to do a string-wise match, or, if you want to search by value, use `$found = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return in_array('824103', explode(',', $v));}); if (!empty($found)) { ...`

Comment: @RobEyre FYI, using empty() considered a bad practice. A better approach would be to use either implicit casting, `if ($found)`, or, if you want your code to be strict - `if ($found !== [])`

Comment: Better yet, loop through the file using `fgetcsv()` and look for the exact value in the exact field that you expect it to be.